# Retrieve multiple columns value from Cassandra using Hector client

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I am working with Cassandra and I am using Hector client to read and upsert the data in Cassandra database. I am trying to retrieve the data from Cassandra database using hector client and I am able to do that if I am trying to retrieve only one column.

Now I am trying to retrieve the data for `rowKey as 1011` but with columnNames as collection of string. Below is my API that will retrieve the data from Cassandra database using Hector client-

```
public Map<String, String> getAttributes(String rowKey, Collection<String> attributeNames, String columnFamily) {

    final Cluster cluster = CassandraHectorConnection.getInstance().getCluster();       
    final Keyspace keyspace = CassandraHectorConnection.getInstance().getKeyspace();

    try {

        ColumnQuery<String, String, String> columnQuery = HFactory
                .createStringColumnQuery(keyspace)
                .setColumnFamily(columnFamily).setKey(rowKey)
                .setName("c1");

        QueryResult<HColumn<String, String>> result = columnQuery.execute();
        System.out.println("Column Name from cassandra: " + result.get().getName() + "Column value from cassandra: " + result.get().getValue());

    } catch (HectorException e) {
        LOG.error("Exception in CassandraHectorClient::getAttributes " +e+ ", RowKey = " +rowKey+ ", Attribute Names = " +attributeNames);
    } finally {
        cluster.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }


    return null;

}
```

If you see my above method, I am trying to retrieve the data from Cassandra database for a particular `rowKey` and for `column c1`. Now I am trying to retrieve the data from Cassandra database for collection of columns for a particular rowKey.

Meaning something like this-

I want to retrieve the data for multiple columns but for the same rowKey. How can I do this using Hector client? And I don't want to retrieve the data for all the columns and then iterate to find out the individual columns data I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use column name made up with composite key as combination of UTF8Type and TIMEUUID 
then after

```
sliceQuery.setKey("your row key");

Composite startRange = new Composite();
startRange.addComponent(0, "c1",Composite.ComponentEquality.EQUAL);

Composite endRange = new Composite();
endRange.addComponent(0, "c1",Composite.ComponentEquality.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL);

sliceQuery.setRange(startRange,endRange, false, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

QueryResult<ColumnSlice<Composite, String>> result = sliceQuery.execute();
ColumnSlice<Composite, String> cs = result.get();
```

above code will give you all records for you row key
after that iterate as follows

```
for (HColumn<Composite, String> col : cs.getColumns()) {
System.out.println("column key's first part : "+col.getName().get(0, HFactoryHelper.stringSerializer).toString());
System.out.println("column key's second part : "+col.getName().get(1, HFactoryHelper.uuidSerializer).toString());
System.out.println("column key's value : "+col.getValue());
}
```

some where you have to write logic to maintain set of records