# "Could not get input splits" Error, with Hive-Cassandra-CqlStorageHandler

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, hiveql

Im trying to read data from cassandra using Hive with CqlStorageHandler.

**The versions:**

Hive 0.11.0
Hadoop 1.2.1
Cassandra 1.2.6

Im able to create EXTERNAL table with the following HIVE Query

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE input(number string,name string,address string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.CqlStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("cassandra.columns.mapping" = ":key, name, address", "cassandra.ks.name" ="cassandradb", "cassandra.host" = "localhost" ,"cassandra.port" = "9160") TBLPROPERTIES ("cassandra.input.split.size" = "64000","cassandra.range.size" = "1000","cassandra.slice.predicate.size" = "1000");

(The table "input" is already existing and containing some data in cassandra created with CQL3)

However, When I try to read data with the following query

select * from input where number="1";

**Im facing the folowing issue:**

Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1

Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
java.io.IOException: Could not get input splits
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.input.cql.HiveCqlInputFormat.getSplits(HiveCqlInputFormat.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.input.cql.HiveCqlInputFormat.getSplits(HiveCqlInputFormat.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1081)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "143514173170822869679056708180186660043"
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:185)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "143514173170822869679056708180186660043"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:444)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:540)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner$1.fromString(Murmur3Partitioner.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat$SplitCallable.call(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:239)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat$SplitCallable.call(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:207)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.IOException(Could not get input splits)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

Am I missing anything? Kindly advise.

Comment: Is a simple select working without the where clause?

Comment: On the first look, appears to be a bug in Cassandra.  As a workaround, could you try specifying a `RandomPartitioner` in `cassandra.yaml` instead of `Murmur3Partitioner`?  Unfortunately, you'll have to wipe your Cassandra installation to change partitioners, but it may be acceptable if you're just prototyping (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865710/cassandra-randompartitioner-on-version-1-2-3 for details).

Comment: @Neels I have solved this issue by changing from RandomPartitioner to Murmur3Partioner.
Simple Hive select query is working without where clause. However facing an issue again while using the "where" clause in hive query.
Issue:
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.io.IOException: Cannot create an instance of InputSplit class = org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.input.HiveCassandraStandardSplit:org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.input.HiveCassandraStandardSplit

Comment: @DanielS. I have solved this issue by changing from RandomPartitioner to Murmur3Partioner.
Simple Hive select query is working without where clause. However facing an issue again while using the "where" clause in hive query.
Issue:
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.io.IOException: Cannot create an instance of InputSplit class = org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.input.HiveCassandraStandardSplit:org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.input.HiveCassandraStandardSplit