# Error while executing query on shark shell with DSE 4.5

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am using datastax 4.5 and trying to use shark .i am able to open shark shell but queries are not working ,Error is :

shark> use company2;
OK
Time taken: 0.126 seconds
shark> select count(*) from nhanes;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not get input splits
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1020)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:888)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver.processCmd(SharkCliDriver.scala:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver$.main(SharkCliDriver.scala:240)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver.main SharkCliDriver.scala
    FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from shark.execution.SparkTask
```

Any idea about this error?

My second question is related to backup.
As i am using opscenter for taking backup but in production is it reliable or do i go for nodetool backup and schedule it on individual node.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check ["Could not get input splits" Error, with Hive-Cassandra-CqlStorageHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853078/could-not-get-input-splits-error-with-hive-cassandra-cqlstoragehandler). You can first test it using hive. If it fails in hive, you need check you keyspace partitioner. I would suggest to create a clean new keyspace and table to test it. Most likely it's something wrong with your KS settings. You can also check the replication of the keyspace, make sure it's replicated to the datacenter the cassandra node starts.

For the second question, it's recommend to use opscenter to backup which is fully tested and easy to use. You can also manually backup by using node tool for each node which causes some human error.